# Sending IP by email on sturtup

Tags: raspbian, python, boot, sendemail, sockets

I'm trying to make my RP accessible over shh on WIFI, but I don't have control over my router (I live in student dorms) and I cannot config a static IP, so I wrote a python script that will get the current IP and send it to my gmail account.
Then I added the script to `crontab`.

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
import struct
import fcntl

import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
ip = socket.inet_ntoa(fcntl.ioctl(s.fileno(), 0x8915, struct.pack('256s', 'wlan0'[0:15])[20:24]))

msg = MIMEText(ip)

msg['Subject'] = 'RP IP'
msg['From'] = '****@gmail.com'
msg['To'] = '****@gmail.com'

try:
       mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)

        #Login to SMTP server
        mail.starttls()
        mail.login('****@gmail.com', my_pass)

        mail.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], 'Subject: RP IP\n\nThe Current IP 
        mail.quit

        print "Success!"
except SMTPException:
        print "Error"
```

The problem is that the scripts returns an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Programming/python/send_ip_by_mail.py", line 11, in <module>
    ip = socket.inet_ntoa(fcntl.ioctl(s.fileno(), 0x8915, struct.pack('256s', 'wlan0'[0:15])[20:24]))
IOError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

When I run the script myself it works fine, but on startup it does not.
What is the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to RPi.se! The problem you are facing is a generic Unix/Linux issue, not specific to the Raspberry Pi. I am flagging this question for migration to [Unix & Linux StackExchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I'm not a python user but I am sure the code as posted has more explicit errors in it than that one, and would not work to do anything no matter where or when you invoked it.  I'm also going to hazard a guess that you cargo culted it from somewhere, because if you understood it properly yourself, I think you would be asking a somewhat different question.  I suggest you try to decipher that line by consulting python docs and figure out what that error means, which should be a big clue as to why it happens.   In any case, python programming questions belong on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yeah, no need for a sledgehammer.  Just use the bash trick of reverse apostrophes like so:  echo \`ifconfig\` | ssmtp myusername@gmailcom and it will do an ifconfig and send you the results.  -->  instructions for setting up ssmtp are found in the bottom answer at:  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/12405/how-to-set-up-smtp-and-send-emails/70535#70535 - those apostrophes are found on the tilde key.

Comment: Of course, your OP doesn't specify why you want this, and what format you would prefer them to be in, or any of that.  Sending ifconfig will tell you the answer, but yet may not solve your unspecified problem.  So I can't post this as an answer because I am not really sure what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't help with your Python, but this strikes me as using a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

I have `avahi` on my Pi so I can "discover" the IP with hostname.local. I am pretty sure avahi starts automatically on newer kernels, or by `dhcpcd`.

I connect with `ssh pi@hostname.local`.

This may not work with older Windows (due to the non standard use of `.local`), but it is worth a try.

Comment: I will check it out and come back to you.

Comment: It's working! but I have a problem with it... I installed a `mysql` server on it, and now I cannot access it with the avahi url. Can you help me with that? or should I open a new question?

Comment: Again, I don't know mysql, but once you are connected it is easy to get the IP e.g. `ping pi@hostname.local` You should ask a new question (with more detail) if you want help.